# Possible way to determine which application generates certain sounds on my system?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Every now and then (e.g. twice a day) I hear a strange - brief - sound on my computer (Windows 7), that I believe to be from a background application like Windows Live Messenger, Teamviewer, Skype or some such.

Is there a direct way of finding/tracing the origin of that sound; without disabling all the applications and then turning each on one at a time?

I'm thinking something like "[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) for Sounds" that I can activate and then have a log created whenever a sound is generated?

**Update 2011-07-24**

Ha! Just heard that sound again. It was approx. 1 second long and sounded like [the chirping of a cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_%28insect%29#Cricket_chirping) ([Here is a sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Field_cricket_Gryllus_pennsylvanicus.ogg)).

Comment: Do they seem to happen at the same time every day? I am thinking there may some scheduled task in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools>Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks, @KCotreau I'll check this. I think it appear at random times.

Comment: I use all the programs you mentioned (although Skype not as much), and I have never had them make random noises. Perhaps you can describe the noise. Is it a beep, or more like some sound like from a wave file? For the record, I can't say there isn't one, but I don't know of any program that tracks noises.

Comment: Best bet that you try to record it and upload it.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not actually a cricket? :-)

Comment: @Joe Yes, pretty sure. My girlfriend is a veterinarian, I asked her to double-check and she confirmed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out the cause of the sounds: It was a notification sound whenever a visitor navigates to our support chat [LiveZilla](http://www.livezilla.net/home/en/) on our website.

Following is a screenshot of the (German) options dialog of LiveZilla:

[image: Live!Zilla]

I now solved my issue of the random sounds, although the question about a "Sound trace" still seems to be answerable by only: "Not available".

Comment: It isn't a good solution since it does not hint anything related to the key point [[[HOW?]]]

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way I can think of is to use the **Volume Mixer**. It lists all the processes that are currently using the speaker as you can see here:

[image: Volume Mixer]

How to start the volume mixer:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→**"sndvol"**→<kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Alternative Solution:

It seems [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is the Process Monitor for sounds. You can set a `Path` filter for common audio format extensions like `WAV` and start capturing events. The relevant process that played the audio file should then be listed in Process Monitor.

1. Set the `Path` filter to include entries that contain `WAV`
   [image: Process Monitor Filter]
2. Start capturing and wait for the process to play the sound
   [image: ProcMon capture]
3. Look at the output to figure out which operations don't keep recurring and create an `Operation` filter to **exclude** all other operations and separate the signal from the noise
   [image: ProcMon - Include QueryOpen]
4. You should see a filtered list of processes with the sounds they've played
   [image: ProcMon - Filtered List]

---

**NOTE:** You might not be able to detect **ALL** programs that play a sound with this method (e.g. Google Chrome playing a YouTube video) but this should satisfy your need for logging sound plays.

Comment: As of writing, my question was for Windows 7. Does your answer work for Window 7, too?

Comment: @UweKeim Yes, this how Win 7 works as well.

Comment: @UweKeim I don't have access to a Windows 7 machine at the moment but [the new Volume Mixer has been around since Windows Vista](http://www.wintuts.com/Volume-Mixer) so it should work

Comment: @UweKeim seems to work fine on Win7. Not sure how long applications producing sound stay there after the sound is finished, but it definitely shows them.

Comment: This looks like a winner with your latest update! Process Monitor was *exactly* what I was looking for.

Comment: @MatthewG. I'm glad to be of help.

Comment: Process monitor is a nice way indeed, but only when sounds are stored as proper sound files on the disk. This is not always the case... for example some applications have WAVE resources inside the EXE file... Process Monitor would not detect them.

Comment: @Ale I did mention that in my answer at the bottom as a note. I haven't used Process Monitor extensively but it does log a **lot** of information. I theorize that with the right filters maybe you can detect playback of WAVE resources inside the executable. This is just speculation of course.

Comment: @Vinayak sorry, I didn't notice that remark, for some reason I stopped reading after the last screenshot. Concerning detecting the playing of a WAVE resource, what you will see in Process Monitor is the loading of data from the EXE (if the resource is not yet in memory), reading audio-related registry keys (e.g. HKCU\Software\Multimedia\Audio) and loading of audio-related files (e.g. MP3 audio codec for a MP3-encoded WAV file). So yes, you can indeed deduce that the application is producing some audio or at least trying to...

Answer (score 2):

A possible way to trace sound generation would be to monitor calls to the various audio/multimedia APIs using an API monitor. I sometimes used http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor, it is very powerful (and moreover free); unfortunately, I didn't see an option to automatically attach to new processes, which means that you would need to manually attach the API monitoring program to every new program you start. And if you are using a 64-bit version of Windows, you would even need to run both 32-bit and 64-bit versions at the same time to be able to monitor both kinds of processes... so, possible but heavy to do.

Here is an example of Skype generating a ringtone, while intercepting calls to audio/video APIs (it did more than 1.5k API calls to produce that sound!):

[image: APIMonitor monitoring audio API calls on Skype.exe during ringtone]